# SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces Fail Issue

Tags: c++, windows, handle

I am having a issue getting this above feature to work. I have read MSDN and under the docs and this is what I come up with however it fails.

So I have used SetupDiGetClassDevs to make a list of all devices and store then to a handle. Which works ok then the next step is to enumerate each device using SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces and passimg the handle value. Here is where I have lost it this always returns false. Would appreciate some advice on where I gone wrong. Thanks for reading.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"SetupAPI") 
//
int main() 
{
    // Set up handles and data storage
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    // Load GUID Classes
    static GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB={ 0xf18a0e88, 0xc30c, 0x11d0, {0x88, 0x15, 0x00, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0x06, 0xbe, 0xd8} }; 
    static GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE ={ 0xA5DCBF10L, 0x6530, 0x11D2, { 0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED } }; 
    static GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER={ 0x3abf6f2d, 0x71c4, 0x462a, {0x8a, 0x92, 0x1e, 0x68, 0x61, 0xe6, 0xaf, 0x27}}; 
    // 
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA ifdata;
    // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    //
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hDevInfo)
        {
        return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Device info set handle for all devices attached to system: 0x%x\n", hDevInfo);
        }
    //
    BOOL bResult = TRUE;
    DWORD nCount = 0;
    //
        while (bResult)
        {
        //
            ifdata.cbSize=sizeof(ifdata);
            //  
            bResult = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
            hDevInfo,  
            NULL,   
            &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE,   
            (ULONG)nCount,  
            &ifdata); 


        //
        if(!bResult)
            {       
            printf("Error Failed\n");       
            //fails here with error 6 invalid handle 
            }
        }



    // Cleanup
    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    //
    system ("pause");
    //
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `SetupDiGetClassDevs` is incorrect because the device information sets elements it returns end up lacking the device interface lists which `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` needs to work.

See the remarks section of the [`SetupDiGetClassDevs` documentation on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To return devices that support a device interface of any class, set
>   the DIFCF_DEVICEINTERFACE flag, set the DIGCF_ALLCLASSES flag, and set
>   ClassGuid to NULL. The function adds to the device information set a
>   device information element that represents such a device and then adds
>   to the device information element a device interface list that
>   contains all the device interfaces that the device supports.

So fix your `SetupDiGetClassDevs` call by adding the `DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE` flag like:

```
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,0,0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I amended the data as you said but the error is still showing up for the SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces command. Which is error 6 handle invalid. The SetupDiGetClassDevs part is parsing fine. Can you see anything else it could be? regards

Comment: Ok fixed now it was working just show last error was returning incorrect report.

Comment: @CliveAtkins, it was a bad idea to edit your code so that it became correct tho ...